# Selenium python iterate over multiple elements

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Basically my problem is that I can't remember how to do it, I remember being able to print out specific elements some how involving **[3] or [ ]**,

I'm using `driver.find_element_by_class_name('classname').click` to click on say the 3rd item or for it to work it's way from top to bottom, I want to be able to loop this but what I have at the moment it just repeatedly clicks on the first item rather than go through the entire length of items that I have asked for?

It's 3:36am I'm tired in bed and not at my desk, If I need to provide more information I'll have to post in a few hours thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use array notation, e.g. [1] or [2], you need a collection/array. In order to get a collection of elements using Selenium, you need to use `.find_elements_*` (note the plural, elementS). From there, you can get what you want, e.g.

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('classname')[1].click()
```

You can put that in a loop, replace the 1 with the index, e.g.

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('classname')[index].click()
```

and so on.